# How can I find the largest bipartite graph?

Tags: approximation, bipartite-graph

A bipartite graph corresponds to a rectangle of ones in the adjacency matrix of this graph.

Having a sparse graph, I would like to find the largest approximated bipartite graph.

approximated means that some edges not in the sparse graph will be in the bipartite graph.

I think this problem can be reformulated in: Given the adj. matrix of a sparse graph, find the shuffling of the columns (or row, adj is symmetric) which leads to the largest dense region of ones in this matrix.

Comment: What is the definition of "dense region"?

Comment: a part of the adj matrix which has lots of ones